# PHP - Sanitize inputs for hashtags, allowing arabic, hebrew, japanese, etc., and emoji?

Tags: php, regex, security

I'm looking at sanitizing inputs for a hashtag search engine.

Effectively I want to allow all alphanumeric characters, cyrillic, arabic, hebrew, etc., as well as emoji characters, but strip any symbols other than underscore.

After spending an hour or so looking online I haven't yet found a conclusive answer. Is there a regex that would enable me to sanitize such an input? Basically remove anything that isn't alphanumeric / letters / emojis.

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: I don't think this can be solved with a regular expression, but you might get further by researching unicode and especially character properties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property

Answer (score 0):

I would basically enable Unicode and match

`/emoji-regex(*SKIP)(?!)|[^\p{L}\p{Nd}_]+/u`

and replace with nothing.

There is a negative class `[^ ]` (meaning not these) of:

```
\p{L}   All letters  
\p{Nd}  Number digits  
_       Underscore
```

The emoji-regex was deleted because of its size.
Edit this answer and grab it if needed.

This regex will *SKIP* the emoji by moving the search position past
them until it finds a block of 1 or more  ***`Non-Letters/Digits/Underscore`*** characters.